# How do I get three stars on "The Pit" in Special Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I've completed the campaign mode of *Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2* and I want to complete Special Ops. I'm stuck on "The Pit". We have to complete the level in 35 seconds to get three stars. I was only able to get two stars no matter how many times or how hard I tried. Can you give me some suggestions (e.g., shoot from the hip, or shoot while running rather than aiming down)?

Comment: Well, I started playing multiplayer and it improved my game a lot. Now, completing Spec Ops is very easy for me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the pistol you start with and the Deagle. Line up your shots so one bullet takes out two targets (possible 3 or so times).

Switch to the other pistol instead of reloading.

Comment: This is the best way to go. I, now, manage to complete the pit within 25-30 seconds easily.

Answer (score 13):

It's much easier with a co-op partner. When I did it, we split the targets between us in a predefined fashion so we had the whole run choreographed. I think aiming is necessary but only for a split second i.e. aim-shoot all at once.

Comment: You ABSOLUTELY have to do them in co-op. Some of them are pretty much impossible any other way. Especially some of the Echo's.  They are all possible though (I've done it!), but definitely find a buddy.

Comment: Co-op obviously helps but you need to get your accuracy, weapon choice and reload/weapon-change timing sorted before you can do it. Otherwise the other player will just be carrying you. If you practice and think about what weapons to use and where each shot goes it's totally do-able solo.

Answer (score 3):

The key to completing The Pit in under 30 seconds is accuracy. The more accurate you are, the higher your bonus and the more seconds that are knocked off your actual time to give your final "score" time.

If you hit any civilians, forget it - start again.

Also, try and make use of the "snap" auto-targeting feature if you have the opportunity.

Other than that, it's just practice. It can be done solo - I did it a few weeks ago myself.

Comment: +1 These are the real keys to this mission (co-op obviously helps but is no good without these points). The key to the pit is absolutely accuracy. I did the pit on vet solo as well. Don't hit any civilians, you'll need almost all of your shots to hit (auto-targeting is crucial). I used 2 pistols (don't remember which ones) as they seemed best for getting off accurate shots quickly and fast reloading.

Answer (score 3):

I did it solo, after a gazillion tries, found out that lining up targets is the key, and reloading as rarely as possible.

Use the MP5, its aim-down-sight (ADS) and reload time is shorter than others.
Run between targets, ADS, fire single shots, AIS, repeat.
Melee the target at the top of the stairs, reload before jumping down.

Comment: If you're sufficiently accurate, you don't need to reload. If I have to reload my gun, I start over as if I'd shot a civilian.

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose your guns: I recommend ACR and M9 Tactical.
2. Switch weapons: In the house, as soon Shepard says `MELEE` Switch to your pistol, continue like that.
3. Practise: Don't just think it'll be a one time miracle, practise.
4. Don't hit civilians.

Answer (score 1):

Keep moving....the game itself gives you hints: if you listen to the voices talking as you negotiate the course you hear something about using the Desert Eagle.

I personally used the M9 and the .45, but the Eagle is good. Pistols are faster to change to, and you also seem to move quicker.

You can still auto aim as you move, it will slow you down a bit but not too much. You can move and shoot at the same time in other words. Hitting two targets is key, you have the possibility of doing it five times (I think).

At the third set of targets inside the house, change weapons at the top of the stairs as the dude yells "melee".

Once outside, If you've got double targets straight in front of you nail them, otherwise turn to your right and nail them (if you don't get the sync for hitting double targets here, I found shooting right to left is the fastest).

Reload before you jump and take out the two targets on the left simultaneously, then move right. Nail these guys here, the hit your two final targets.

Remember, move at all times. Its the only way I found to beat the obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

There are some perfectly workable solutions here already, here's another.

I often run through the pit before a play session in order to warm up and "calibrate" my thumbs. If I'm not hitting stationary targets without any lag, I'm not going to hit moving ones in an actual game.

My goal is to get through in under 30 seconds twice in a row. With the M4.

Since I'm warming up for actual play, I use a real weapon like I'd use in the game. You could use one of the other weapons beside the M4 if that's more your style, such as the SCAR or the MP5. You should be able to get all the way through the course without reloading, so don't worry about your secondary weapon.

You can get through without reloading by firing single bullets, rather than bursts. You can get away with firing a few 2-3 shot bursts, but too many of those and you'll have to reload, ruining everything.

It's also very helpful to line up targets and hit two at a time. This also helps conserve ammo.

Double opportunities:

- Before you enter the first room, you can line up one of the targets at the sandbags with the one moving back and forth in the lower room windows.
- Depending on your timing, you might be able to line up some of the targets at the top of the stairs, after using your knife.
- After jumping down you can line up almost every target with another one. The one on the far left lines up with one deep. You can aim at the deep one as you're falling, and once the close one is in the way, shoot.
- At the very end, don't even aim at the targets in front of the exit tunnel. You can hip fire right through the one in front and hit the back, consuming whatever bullets you have left. Sprint to the end with your empty gun.

Comment: For me, In terms of best time possible, I found it easier to use two pistols - as you seem to run slightly faster with them rather than the M4 or MP5. Further to this, the 'fast switch to secondary' counts for both pistols. The M9 has a large clip, and the USP.45 has the tactical knife for the melee section.

Comment: @Robotnik I've gotten slightly faster times using two pistols, that's true. I wasn't trying to answer how to get the fastest time, though, as that's not the question. You do run a bit faster with the pistol than with the M4, but not faster than with the MP5. Submachine guns and pistols have full run speed. Assault rifles are slightly less. 97.5%, I think. Or maybe it was 92.5%. Pistols have the advantage of not slowing you down when looking down the sights, also.